# Reference or guide for standard texts for GUI

Tags: qt, user-interface, text, standards

I'm a GUI developer using Qt targetting cross-platform. Whenever I add a new component of GUI, especially dialogs, buttons, and menus, I suffer for what text  I should use.
For instance, when adding a button to select an existing folder, I can think of 3 candidates: "Select", "Open", or "Browse". Also, I'm not sure if I should append ... like Browse... or not.
I have problems to decide the title of dialogs, too. For example, for a dialog to save a file, 'Save', 'Save...', or 'Save a file'...

I do know the specific text may be difference depending on desktop envrironment or OSes, which makes things more complicated.
Is there any reference or guide or library or anything which can help my situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are user interface guidelines on the web:

1) OS X: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html)

2) Windows: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465424.aspx)

3) For KDE i found the following reference: [link](http://techbase.kde.org/Projects/Usability/HIG)

4) For GNOME check this out: [link](https://developer.gnome.org/hig-book/stable/)

When it comes to "Save" vs "Save ...": I would suggest to use the ellipsis if the user has to activly do something after pressing the button (e.g. choose a file).